# How set up alarm with the same ID for selected days?

Tags: java, android

I have two variable:

- howManyDays - how many days alarm should work
- cal - start date

---

Unfortunatelly my code doesn't work - alarm doesn't show. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Can I make the same ID for many alarms to fast delete it? If you have any question just let me know.

---

```
int howManyDays= Integer.parseInt(countDays.getText().toString());

Cursor c = myDb.getID_REMINDER();
c.moveToFirst();
int id = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));

Intent intx = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
intx.putExtra("Value", nameOfMedicine.getText().toString());

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intx, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

for(int i=0; i<=howManyDays; i++) {
       Calendar cc = cal;
       cc.add(cc.DATE, i);
       alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cc.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting multiple alarms, you can just set a repeating alarm. For that you will have to provide the repeating interval in mili seconds as follows

```
Intent intx = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    intx.putExtra("Value", nameOfMedicine.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("requestCode", id);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intx, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


    long repeatingInterval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 day

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            repeatingInterval, pendingIntent);
```

Keep in mind that there is no way to set an alarm for howManyDays in Android. One possible and low processing solution is to set two alarms; one is repeating alarm and the second is fixed alarm for the last day. When the second alarm will be fired after howManyDays, it will cancel the first repeating alarm.

Comment: I want to repeat alarm for howManyDays

Comment: and your alarm will be working everyday until end of the world :/

Comment: There is no way for that in Android. One possible and low processing solution is to set two alarms; one is repeating alarm and the second is fixed alarm for the last day. When the second alarm will be fired after howManyDays, it will cancel the first repeating alarm.